# Querying inlineHelpText using the tooling API

Tags: tooling-api, fielddefinition

From my small experiments it seems that this field isn't queryable through the Tooling API.
Using this query here:

```
https://www.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,+DeveloperName,+inlineHelpText+from+FieldDefinition+where QualifiedApiName='Account'
```

This returns

```
[
    {
        "message": "\nSelect Id, DeveloperName, inlineHelpText from FieldDefinition\n                          ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:27\nNo such column 'inlineHelpText' on entity 'FieldDefinition'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
    }
]
```

Skipping the inLineHelpText from the query returns results so it seems that I can't retrieve this field data.  Has anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "inlineHelpText" appears in the [FieldDefintion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) docs it isn't in the context of a field on FieldDefinition. It appears under the **CustomField Metadata**. Which is the metadata you get on fields against other objects. Not against the FieldDefinition itself.

You can confirm this with the following Apex:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/TraceFlag/describe/');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

That JSON that comes back from that describe is for what you can query about a FieldDefinition. You'll notice that **inlineHelpText** doesn't appear as the **name** of the field.

Instead it comes back as metadata on the FieldDefinition fields.

E.g. The Tooling API `FieldDefinition.Id` has a null value for the **inlineHelpText**.

[image]

So, in conclusion, if you want to see the **inlineHelpText** you do a describe on the sObject in question rather than looking directly at the FieldDefintion.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is indeed available through the Metadata API, just ran a few retrieves through Workbench and got my inlineHelpText fix there.